# Amplitude & Segment.io - Saas product analytics - How to get all users

Tags: analytics, segment-io, amplitude-analytics

if I want to calculate the % of active users for my product. I need the total amount of users for each day. How can I achieve this with Segment.io and Amplitude?

Do I need to send an event every day with the number of all users?

Answer (score 0):

Start off with Amplitude I would advice. I don't know your use case extensively but it seems you are adding unnecessary complexity to the flow.

You can then export data to Segment if you feel the need to do so later on.